# Auto completar varias cajas de texto 2

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

He encontrado un ejemplo el cual funciona a la perfección para auto completar varios input text desde una consulta a mysql.

El ejemplo constaba de 5 input y yo le he añadido un sexto.
Al hacer la modificación el sript seguía funcionando como al inicio, solo añadía valores a los 5 input y el que yo he añadido extra no lo auto completaba.

Pero este ejemplo también tiene un botón para duplicar el formulario y en el duplicado si que carga el valor de el input "poblacion" que es el que no constaba en el ejemplo de inicio.

Me gustaría saber porque no carga el valor del input poblacion en la primera consulta, pero si cuando añadimos un segundo y un tercer formulario.

Cuando añado un cuarto formulario el scrip deja de funcionar por completo y ya no hace nada.

Os dejo los archivos y el link a la demo de mi sitio:

http://www.buendialogistica.com/index.html/ejemplo2/index.php

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>How to autocomplete data on multiple fields with jQuery and AJAX</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href='jquery-ui.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' >
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('keydown', '.username', function() {

                var id = this.id;
                var splitid = id.split('_');
                var index = splitid[1];

                $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "getDetails.php",
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                search: request.term,request:1
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                response( data );
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                        var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                        // AJAX
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'getDetails.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {userid:userid,request:2},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success:function(response){

                                var len = response.length;

                                if(len > 0){
                                    var id = response[0]['id'];
                                    var name = response[0]['name'];
                                    var email = response[0]['email'];
                                    var age = response[0]['age'];
                                    var salary = response[0]['salary'];
                                    var poblacion = response[0]['poblacion'];

                                    document.getElementById('name_'+index).value = name;
                                    document.getElementById('age_'+index).value = age;
                                    document.getElementById('email_'+index).value = email;
                                    document.getElementById('salary_'+index).value = salary;
                                    document.getElementById('poblacion_'+index).value = poblacion;

                                }

                            }
                        });

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });

            // Add more
            $('#addmore').click(function(){

                // Get last id 
                var lastname_id = $('.tr_input input[type=text]:nth-child(1)').last().attr('id');
                var split_id = lastname_id.split('_');

                // New index
                var index = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;

                // Create row with input elements
                var html = "<tr class='tr_input'><td><input type='text' class='username' id='username_"+index+"' placeholder='Enter username'></td><td><input type='text' class='name' id='name_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='age' id='age_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='email' id='email_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='salary' id='salary_"+index+"' ></td><td><input type='text' class='poblacion' id='poblacion_"+index+"' ></td></tr>";


                // Append data
                $('tbody').append(html);

            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Poblacion</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class='tr_input'>
                <td><input type='text' class='username' id='username_1' placeholder='Enter username'></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='name' id='name_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='age' id='age_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='email' id='email_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='salary' id='salary_1' ></td>
                <td><input type='text' class='poblacion' id='poblacion_1' ></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type='button' value='Add more' id='addmore'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

getDetails.php

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$request = $_POST['request'];   // request

// Get username list
if($request == 1){
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like'%".$search."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['username']);
    }

    // encoding array to json format
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

// Get details
if($request == 2){
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$userid;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $users_arr = array();

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $userid = $row['id'];
        $fullname = $row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $age = $row['age'];
        $salary = $row['salary'];
        $poblacion = $row['poblacion'];

        $users_arr[] = array("id" => $userid, "name" => $fullname,"email" => $email, "age" =>$age, "salary" =>$salary, "poblacion" =>$poblacion);
    }

    // encoding array to json format
    echo json_encode($users_arr);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funcionando.

Me había dejado un guion bajo en dos partes del archivo index.html.
Ahora ya completa el input desde el primer formulario y en el cuarto y siguientes.

He modificado el código de index.html

Un saludo,